# xmlhttp.responseText to html code

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to display an `xmlhttp.responseText` as HTML code and specifically to fill a dropdownbox, however it seems to be processed as a string and not HTML code.

I am using the code that I would like to display in HTML format as various menu `<option>`s in a `<span>` tag

javascript code within the `xmlhttprequest` function:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Code in html that is found within the dropdown menu:

```
< span id="test">

< /span>
```

The php file that is called by the `xmlhttprequest` echo's the following:

```
$option="&lt;option&gt;";
```

(this is in a while loop)

```
{
    echo  $option.$row['productName'].$option="&lt;option&gt;";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like,

```
$str='';
while(1) {
   $str.='<option>'.$row['productName'].'</option>';
}
echo $str;
```

**Also,** `option` should be placed in `drop down list` like `select` not in `span`

So, change your **HTML** like,

```
<select id="test">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want html outcome then use html, don't use special chars.

in your loop use

```
echo "<option>" . $row['productName'] . "</option>";
```